# In Jenkins is possible to mark an aborted job as success?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

In a job where i call terraform apply, after the deploy the shell is stuck and the job doesn't end so i have to abort it. Is it possible to mark the aborted job as success or there is another way to end this job without force?

Comment: How are you invoking terraform exactly? Are you using **Execute Shell** to run the job?

Comment: using terraform apply, in provision.sh the command that block the shell should be "java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://************:8080/computer/terraform/slave-agent.jnlp"

Answer (score 0):

On the job summary/artifacts/changes/triggers/results page you can "add a description". This is a good place to summarize results and explain what happened after job result is reviewed. The first part of description also appears in Build History.

**Answer:** 
In shell scripts (or jenkins job script) you can **use bash timeout command** to protect any command that might get stuck. 'timeout [<option>] <duration> <command>'. e.g.

```
$ timeout 2s sleep 4
$ echo $?
124
```

You can check this exit value in script and exit with success or use the --preserve-status option to timeout to change exit code and have job considered as successful. Although if something is timing out it probably makes most sense to have the job marked as failed ?

Inside jenkins **Execute shell** you can wrap timeout with 'set -e' and 'set +e' so that the non-zero exit code will not be regarded as fail. Something like this would work for you:

```
set -e     # no error if non-zero exit status
timeout <timeout> <terraform hanging command>
set +e
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html

Comment: Thanks for the response,  during the provisioning terraform launch a Jar that remains in listening this is why i want to stop the job without marking it as failed. If the command reach the timeout, the job will be marked as success?

Comment: The exit code of last command of the Jenkin's Execute Shell build step is what determines the success/failure of the Build Step. You say terraform launches the jar. If you use 'timeout <timeout> <terraform jar hanging command>', then after that 'echo "always successful"' then that will always be success.

Comment: Actually see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/143445/what-does-set-e-do-and-why-might-it-be-considered-dangerous/143576#143576   So what you need is to use 'set -e' ' set +e'. I will edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

Appended to the first answer, you have a `set` alternative just piping the semicolon. Nasty workaround in Bash, but works.

```
timeout <timeout> <terraform hanging command> || :
```